# Replace text with regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

This is my text input value:

```
[quote Name Lastname]
text text text text text

    [quote Name2 Lastname2]
    text text text text text
    [end]

[end]
```

I need to transform it in ->

```
<blockquote>
    <span> Name Lastname </span>
    text text text text text

    <blockquote>
        <span> Name Lastname </span>
        text text text text text
    </blockquote>

</blockquote>
```

And make some closures in case the author did not do it.

This is my actual source code:

```
var oldMessage = $('#message').html();

var begin = /\[?quote\s[A-Za-z0-9\s]{1,}]/g;
var end = /\[?end]/g;

var beginMatch = oldMessage.match(begin);
var endMatch = oldMessage.match(end);


var beginMatchCounter = 0;
var endMatchCounter = 0;

if(beginMatch) {beginMatchCounter = oldMessage.match(begin).length;}
if(endMatch) {endMatchCounter = oldMessage.match(end).length}

var missingBegin = endMatchCounter - beginMatchCounter;
var missingEnd = beginMatchCounter - endMatchCounter;

var newMessage = '';


newMessage = newMessage + oldMessage.replace(begin,"<blockqoute>");
newMessage = newMessage.replace(end,"</blockqoute>");

for(var i = 0; i < missingBegin; i++) { newMessage = "<blockqoute>" + newMessage; }

for(var i = 0; i < missingEnd; i++) { newMessage = newMessage + "</blockqoute>"; }

$('#message').html(newMessage);
```

I know i need to use:

```
slice(7, txt.length-1)
```

But don`t know how to do it, should I use forEach?

Comment: You can use simpler code http://jsfiddle.net/j93parnd/

Comment: wow, thank you  @Mohammad